# is it possible to develop a red app that's linked to sabre workspace using PHP or it has to be in Java?

Tags: java, php, sabre

I've done some research regarding the matter, I can see that you can use SOAP or RESTful APIs to make a web application using PHP.
However what I want to accomplish here is to make a red app that can be used with sabre workspace.

I'm not familiar with the work space, i just started learning about it, I've downloaded the developer toolkit and read the documentation, from this I came to the conclusion that the app has to be written in java in order to work with sabre workspace.

I wanted to make sure if that's the only way of doing it.

your help is highly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: i've edited it to delete the part of the certification process, which is not at all the intention of the question @Mureinik

Comment: Retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can build Web Red App application for Sabre Red Workspace. These will be rendered using Eclipse native SWT Browser. Sabre has built some browser wrappers that simplify the implementation of these, allow consumption of Sabre Web Services from Java Script and other Sabre Red APIs in simple way.

Have you had a chance to review the Eclipse Red App Developer Toolkit documentation integrated? These are available after you install the Dev Tools on top of your Eclipse IDE.

thanks!